# Index Match Array formula not working properly

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I am completely stumped with an array formula that will not work. I have researched and tried many different things and continue to get the #N/A error. I am hoping someone here can help me understand.

I have a database of employee skills in a table named "Skills" with three columns. Employee ID, Type and Skill [Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbblz.png)

On another tab I am trying to run an Index Match array to filter employees that have certain skills. I would like to be able to use 1 or more criteria. For example employees that have the skill "Infor" and "syspro" The criteria is in cell A2 and C2

I am attempting to use the following formulas to do this and they are not working. And I am pressing ctrl+shift+enter

```
=INDEX(Skills[Employee ID],MATCH(1,($A$2=Skills[Skill]),0),1)
=INDEX(Skills[Employee ID],MATCH(1,($A$2=Skills[Skill])*($C$2=Skills[Skill]),0),1)
```

Comment: There is no reason to for an array version of the first formula. Change the match part to this: `MATCH($A$2,Skills[Skill],0)` and it is a regular formula and not an array, entered normally with Enter.

Comment: As to the second; with `($A$2=Skills[Skill])*($C$2=Skills[Skill])` you are saying that you are looking for ONE cell that is both equal to A2 AND C2 at the same time, unless A2 = C2 it cannot be done.

Comment: I need to return multiple employees if there are multiple people with that skill. Which is the reason for an array originally.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong formulas completely.  INDEX/MATCH will always only return the first match found and stop.  You want a Pivot Table using a filter.

Comment: The problem is that the way the data is construsted there are multiple rows for the same employee with different skills. If employee 123 has 10 skills then there are 10 rows. I need to be able to find employees that have multiple skills so I need to search the same column multiple times for different values.

Comment: @ScottCraner has the right of it.  This sounds like something you can do with a simple filter, or alternately a pivot table with a filter.  Why does this need to be formulas on a separate sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still recommend using a filter, but if it must be a formula, this should work for you.  Change the `A$3:A3` to the cell above where the formula will be posted (so this formula assumes it is going in cell A4 of the second sheet) and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Skills[Employee ID],MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF(A$3:A3,Skills[Employee ID])=0)*(COUNTIFS(Skills[Employee ID],Skills[Employee ID],Skills[Skill],$A$2)+COUNTIFS(Skills[Employee ID],Skills[Employee ID],Skills[Skill],$C$2)=2),),0)),"")
```